# How to pass a function as an argument in Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, coffeescript

I'm a newbie with Coffeescript, and I want to pass a function as an argument to be used as a callback when an animation is complete.  Right now, my "callback" is being run before my animation completes.

```
  closeItem: ($elem) ->
    @close($elem, @myCallback($elem))

  close: ($elem, callback) ->
    $elem.slideUp 300, (-> callback)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are calling your function when you call `close`.  We are overloading terms here, but you seem like you want to "close" over the `$elem` variable to make this happen.  Try this:

```
closeItem: ($elem) ->
    @close $elem, => @myCallback($elem)

close: ($elem, callback) ->
    $elem.slideUp 300, callback
```

Notice a few things:

We are using the fat arrow `=>` in the call to `@close`.  This creates a function with the context of the current object, so that it can call `@callback` and it then closes upon `$elem` so that it can be passed to `@myCallback`

Also, in the `close` function itself, you just pass the callback along to `slideUp`

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for explaining why my previous setup was incorrect.